Бесконечный цикл while C++
Пишу простой калькулятор на С++ (изучаю классы). При проверке деления на ноль, continue переходит на следующую итерацию цикла, а при проверке isdigit() цикл становится бесконечным.
Сам класс:
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

double Calc::Calculate(double a, char operation, double b)
{
    switch (operation)
    {
    case '+':
        return a + b;
    case '-':
        return a - b;
    case '*':
        return a * b;
    case '/':
        return a / b;
    default:
        return 0.0;
    }
}


Проверка и вывод:
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> a >> operation >> b;

        if ( !(isdigit(a)) || !(isdigit(b)) ) {
            cout << "Я считаю только числа :(\n";
            continue;
        }
        else if (b == 0 && operation == '/') {
            cout << "На ноль дельть нельзя!\n";
            continue;
        }
        else {
            result = c.Calculate(a, operation, b);
            cout << a << " " << operation << " " << b << " = " << result << endl;
        }
        
    } 


Зачем вам нужна проверка isdigit, если вы считываете из ввода числа с двойной точностью double?

честно говоря, писал по методичке. а хочется обычный калькулятор для различных вычислений. какой тип посоветуете использовать?

Всё довольно просто, вы сделали бесконечный цикл и не добавили возможность выйти из него.
Пусть у вас будет специальный символ выхода, допустим ;.
Тогда надо сделать проверку на выход следующим образом:
if (operation == ';') break; 

Также вам надо тип заменить a и b на тип double. Чтоб вам не надо было добавлять проверки. Вы можете удалить проверки is_digit и всё будет работать. Только придётся в default написать обработку не корректного ввода.
Если же вы хотите a и b оставить строкой, то можно добавить проверку (пусть a и b будут типом string).
is_number(string a)
{
    bool has_point = false;

    for(auto symbol : a)
    {
        if (symbol == '.')
        {
            if(!has_point) has_point = true;
            else return false;
        }

        else if(!is_digit(symbol)) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

Теперь надо заменить is_digit на is_number в проверке на число.

а если хочется один вывод "Я считаю только числа :(\n", а потом снова принимать аргументы для вычеслений?

@Никита, можно и так, но цикл будет бесконечным. Потому что из него нельзя будет выйти.

а как так сделать?) continue бесконечно выводит фразу "Я считаю только числа :(\n", а должен в cin закидывать, как в случае деления на ноль, когда он выводит 1 раз "На ноль делить нельзя!" и начинает принимать новые аргументы

Просто is_digit проверяет один символ. Щас добавлю возможность проверки.

У меня ведь в классе указан тип double для a и b (double Calc::Calculate(double a, char operation, double b))

@Никита, тогда вам не нужна проверка.

Тогда когда подаю (а+1 например) возвращается 0.0, а хочется снова вводить данные, предупредив пользователя о корректности вводимых значений.  Или лучше в default это прописать?

@Никита, да лучше это прописать в default
